# Computed Column for Adding Date based on another Date and foreign key column

Tags: sql-server, calculated-columns

I have the following columns in the same table say `Authentication`

```
Password_Date (DATETIME, NOT NULL)
Password_Period (INT, FOREIGN KEY of a look-up table)
Password_Cycle (DATETIME, NOT NULL)
```

- The `Password_Date` will store the `datetime`when the user changes password.
- The `Password_Period` is a foreign key column which is referred from a look-up table. (Say its value is 30)
- For the `Password_Cycle`column, I want to add a formula in computed column.
  The formula's logic is to add 30 days(`Password_Period`) with `Password_Date` column.

I tried the formula `([Password_Date]+[Password_Period])` in design view but the data type property for `Password_Cycle` went blank.

Please provide possible solution(s) to get this work.

**NOTE:** I must use a computed column formula only and not functions or procedures.

Answer (score 2):

It goes blank in the SSMS UI because SQL Server works out the datatype itself for computed columns from the expression. This isn't something defined in the designer.

It will be `datetime` though I don't like the `datetime`+`int` syntax and would recommend `DATEADD(DAY, Password_Period, Password_Date)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

In computed columns data types goes blank. If u want to use it later You can always cast it for desired type.